# How does one get the system UUID from a server's BMC?

Tags: pxe-boot, ipmi, ipmitool, bmc, dmidecode

I need the uuid of some systems for ipxe booting purposes.. The problem is that these systems are powered off with no OS on them.  I could power them on, but it would do me little good since they have no OS installed.

I know that the uuid of a system can be obtained by using the command line.

Example:

```
cat /sys/class/dmi/id/product_uuid
```

Is there a way to get the system UUID out of the BMC (using ipmitool mabye)?  If so, what is it?

I already have all of the other services setup to take the machine and install everything.  I only lack the uuid to identify the machine which needs installing.

NOTE: MAC ADDRESSES ARE NO GOOD FOR THIS PURPOSE!
I have way too many nics on these machines and they DO NOT adequately uniquely identify a machine since a machine has multiple mac addresses and there is no way of affirmatively knowing which one to use. Any suggestions to use the mac will be shot down on sight.

Comment: A system UUID exists even in systems without IPMI/BMC. In some systems the UUID might not even be sensible. I have a system where it's literally all zeroes. But I don't see anywhere obvious that it can be found in `ipmitool`.

Comment: Manufactures should be setting the uuid to something sensible.  They are unique enough to get the job done that I need them for.  I'm already powering on the machine through ipmi. It just seems logical that one should be able to obtain uuid from the bmc.  Maybe I should ask for the feature?

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I also found out today that some systems will return a blank UUID if not all of the needed information is suppplied in the bios.  If you have a system which returns a blank or all 0 uuid, you need to check if you can set the product and serial number of the machine since those are used in making the system uuid.  They can be easily set in HP bios which seems to also be the primary offender on not setting those values.

Comment: Attempting to contact the developer's directly on github. https://github.com/ipmitool/ipmitool/issues/7